# Where to add Many to Many in django?

Tags: django

So, Am creating a app where user can add universities to their fav or wishlist ! The problem is, am just confused how and where add ManyToMany ?

```
Model Student:
   name = models.CharField
   .....

Model University:
   name = models.CharField
   .....

Model Wishlist:
   wish = models.ManyToMany(University)
```

Is this correct, is it okay to create a seprate model class as "wishlist" or can i have the wishlist on the Student:

Am totally confused, all i need to do is "user needs to able to click heart button and add university to wishlist and if they reclicks it needs to removed"

Comment: If a student can have *multiple* wishlists (for example with a different name), then the modeling makes sense, otherwise it is better to store this as an m2m in the student model.

Comment: No, they can have only one @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `Student` can only have one wishlist, it makes no sense to define an extra model with a `ManyToManyField`. This would result in creating an extra table, and thus make queries less effective, and programs less readable.

In that case, you can define a `ManyToManyField` from your `Student` to the `University`, so:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    wishlist = models.ManyToManyField('University', blank=True)
    # ⋮

class University(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Comment: Can the ManytoMany be null=True & Blank=True ? or either one is enough ? As you know students may or may not add items to wishlsit !

Comment: @sixovov947: blank means it is not required to fill in a value. `null=True` makes not much sense since that is equivalent to an "empty" relation: so a `Student` which has *no* universities added to the wishlist.

Comment: So, are you suggesting to add blank ? Am not getting

Comment: @sixovov947: yes, but `null` makes no sense, especially since that would result in two values for no wishlist.

Comment: If thats the case, how to add a university to wishlist ? can that single field be updated with m2m ?

Comment: @sixovov947: with a student `mystudent` and a university `myuniversity` you add this with `mystudent.wishlist.add(myuniversity)`.

Comment: Oh, thats intresting ! Let me do this practically ! And by the removing the university also same way ?

Comment: @sixovov947: then it is `.remove(...)` instead of `.add(...)`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ for a manual regarding m2m manipulations.

Comment: Hey, its working perfectly ! but have a small doubt how to check if univeristy exisists ? so that i can remove that when they reclick ?

Comment: @sixovov947: if the university is already removed, a second remove will not change anything. If the user thus clicks twice, and each time you make a `.remove(...)` call, the first one will remove the link to the university, and the second will not have any effect.

Comment: Understood, how to undo the likes ? Example - when a user makes a university as fav and after some days if reclick on the heart button it should undo it ! For that purpose i need to check if its already like right ?

Comment: @sixovov947: can you ask a new question and share the details how you are currently add/(remove) universities to the `wishlist`? Likely people can then provide a solution that is more tailored towards your app.